# Setting up a router VPN alongside company VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I work remotely from home and currently connect to my company network using an OpenVPN Connect client.  At the moment I connect to the internet using a TP Link TL-WDR3600 router.

I would like to upgrade the firmware on my router to either OpenWRT or DD-WRT and setup my home network so that the traffic is routed through a VPN service on the router.

However I am unsure how to configure the network so that when my work VPN is connected it can route without going through the router VPN (I dont want the overhead of a tunnel within a tunnel).

Can someone offer guidance on the best way to configure this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me make sure I get this right: you want your router with the new firmware to act as a VPN client to a remote server, and have all of your home traffic go thru this VPN, **except** for your connection to your work site.

**If** this is correct, then the solution is very simple: just add a routing rule instructing the router to bypass the VPN **only for your work IP address**. Assuming your work IP address to be *1.2.3.4*, your WAN facing interface to be *eth0*, and the IP address of the next hop after your router to be *192.168.1.1*, just issue on the router:

```
ip route add 1.2.3.4/32 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 metric 0
```

Routing rules are applied on the basis of the principle *most specific first*: when several routing rules apply, the most specific one wins, even if it is not the first one on the list (contrary to, say, iptables). And, by not going thru *tun/tap*, the packets are neither compressed nor encrypted.

Comment: Exactly right.  Thanks very much for your help